# ActionScript 3.0 classes: not able to with access stage

Tags: actionscript-3, class, inheritance, singleton, stage

I have three classes Main(document class), Container and Area control.

**Code for Main class**

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import com.andreanaya.areacontrol.Container;
 public class Main extends Container 
    {
        private var _build : Build;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            super();
            if (stage) stageHandler();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageHandler);
        }

        private function stageHandler(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            trace("entry point");
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageHandler);
            // entry point


        }

}
```

**Code for Container class**

```
package com.andreanaya.areacontrol
{
   import flash.display.Sprite;
   import flash.display.Stage;
   import flash.display.DisplayObject;
   import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;


   public class Container extends Sprite
   {

      public function Container() {

         super();
         }
override public function get stage() : Stage {
         trace("$$");
         return AreaControl.stage;
      }
}
}
```

**Code for Area Control class**

```
package com.andreanaya.areacontrol
{
   import flash.display.Sprite;
   import flash.display.Stage;


   public class AreaControl extends Sprite
   {

      public function AreaControl() {
         super();

         if(_instance)
         {

            throw new Error("AreaControl is already instantiated.");
         }
         else
         {

            _instance = this;
            _stage = stage;
            return;
         }
      }

      private static var _instance:AreaControl;

      private static var _stage:Stage;

       static function get stage() : Stage {

         return _stage;
      }

}
}
```

I am not able to access stage from these classes, can any one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need a static variable to store stage? It's already stored in all DisplayObjects and is accessible by *stage* property.

Anyway, your problem is that you don't add your AreaControl object to your display list, so it's *stage* property will always be *null*

Good practice here will be accessing your stage only after the Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE fired. Just like in your Main class.

I would recommend you to review your app architecture, because it's rarely needed to store a global link to the stage anywhere, but if your really need it - you can assign it in your Main class in the *stageHandler*. And you don't need an instance of your *AreaControl* to assign a stage link. You can do this way:

```
package com.andreanaya.areacontrol {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;


    public class AreaControl { //You don't even need to extend it from Sprite

        public static var stage: Stage;

    }
}
```

.......

```
    private function stageHandler(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        trace("entry point");
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, stageHandler);
        // entry point
        // It's not an accident it is called "entry point", you should
        // add your code AFTER this line if you don't want any *stage* issues
        AreaControl = stage; //It's never null here;
    }
```

After your *stageHandler* function fired, you can access your stage with *AreaControl.stage*

There are a bunch of ways to handle static variables and singletons, consider reading more about it. The way I've shown you is far away from optimal

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer, But I can't assign stage to Area Control as "AreaControl = stage". The error I got is "Error #1074: Illegal write to read-only property AreaControl on global." Is there any other way ? Also look at the function in Container class override public function get stage() : Stage {
         trace("$$");
         return AreaControl.stage;
      }

Comment: You didn't change any code in AreaControl class, there's only getter for your stage variable, so it thinks it's read only. Create a setter method or just replace your AreacControl class contents with mine (it's a complete class there, yes, it's that small). And as I said - you won't need any get stage() functions anymore - the link is AreaControl.stage

Comment: Area control class has more code also. Also I need to get stage from Container class. Help me.

Comment: http://pastie.org/8341314
You should create Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE listener in your Container